# Subsets, within Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to learn how to make Excel formulae understand my subsets. An Example:

```
Week    Value   Number  Accept? First
1         a      11     TRUE    a    
1         b      12     TRUE    FALSE
1         c      13     FALSE   FALSE

2         d      13     FALSE   f
2         e      12     FALSE   FALSE
2         f      12     TRUE    FALSE

3         g      12     FALSE   #N/A
3         h      13     FALSE   FALSE
3         i      13     FALSE   FALSE

4         j      14     FALSE   k
4         k      14     TRUE    FALSE
4         l      12     TRUE    FALSE
```

Column A (Week) defines subsets, separated for clarity.
"First" uses the formula

```
=IF(A1<>A2,INDEX($B$1:$B$100,MATCH(A2&TRUE,$A$1:$A$100&$C$1:$C$100,0))
```

Which allows me to select the first value which satisfies condition Accept?, within subsets (It seems rather inefficient, so if anyone has a better idea I'd gladly test it) 
Now imagine the following data:

```
Value   Time    Price Trigger?  
  x       14     500
  a       11     490
  b       12     480
  c       13     320
  d       14     560
  e       15     570     e
  f       16     490
  g       17     520     g
```

X is a comparison value. It has 2 parameters: Time & Price
"Trigger" searches for values in the list that have greater time and price than X (Row 2)

The formula for Trigger would be something like:

```
=IF(AND(B3>$B$2;C3>$C$2);B1;"")
```

But, how do I make this same thing work, within weeks ("subsets")?

Comment: You can easily add a third term to your `AND` expression, i.e. `=IF(AND(B3>$B$2;C3>$C$2,A3=1);B1;"")`

Comment: How would this work on the first example? The subset is defined in column A... I'm afraid I don't see how this would work... thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)):INDEX(D:D,COUNTIF(A:A,"<="&A2)+1),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)):INDEX(D:D,COUNTIF(A:A,"<="&A2)+1),0),2)=B2,FALSE),B2,FALSE)
```

Here is the explanations:

`INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)):INDEX(D:D,COUNTIF(A:A,"<="&A2)+1)`: This is to determine the range/subset that corresponds to the Week, so you will get `$A$2:$D$4, $A$5:$D$7, $A$8:$D$10, $A$11:$D$13` as outcome.

`MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)):INDEX(D:D,COUNTIF(A:A,"<="&A2)+1),0)`: You probably know this already.  This is to satisfy the condition on *Accept column*.  But I have to add another range by using `INDEX` again just for *column Accept*.

Then I used an `IF` function to determine if the result is equal to *Value column*, otherwise will output `FALSE`.  You don't need this if you don't mind the same outcome for every cell on *First column*.

Lastly, I personally don't like those error code so used `IFERROR` to output the error message I prefer.  You can remove that for your preference.

Hope this helps.